# Java JSch Set Max Session Allow

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am attempting to set max allow open session in JSch java code. but i unable to find such configuration to set max session allow configuration. or can we able to check max open connection using jsch.

Comment: Are you talking about the OpenSSH server _MaxSessions_ parameter? You're not going to find a jsch (client) setting to alter a server parameter.

Comment: @ Kenster. I am using jsch java lib to transfer files to sftp server. I need to set max open session in java code or i need to get existing session count in that server.